# Delete newest incoming message in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, smsmanager

i've already done read and recieve incoming message, and now i wanna auto delete incoming message from a specific number (android 4.1-below) when the apps on running, but it didnt work out. im calling delete_thread(); on my BroadcastReciever to delete newest incoming message from 5556(my other emulator).

here's my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static TextView SMSm;
static String phoneNumber1;
static String SMSBody1;



public static void setSmsDetails(String phoneNumber, String SMSBody) {
    phoneNumber1 = phoneNumber;
    SMSBody1 = SMSBody;
    SMSm.setText("Sender :" + phoneNumber + "\nMessage : "+ SMSBody1);

}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SMSm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etSmsBody);
    SMSm.setText("Sender : " + phoneNumber1 + " " + "\nSMS: " +
             SMSBody1);

    //delete_thread("5556");
}

public  void delete_thread(String thread) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //String thread = "5556";
    Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
              Uri.parse("content://sms/"),new String[] { 
              "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date","body" }, null, null, null);
    try {
        while (c.moveToNext()) 
          {
            int id = c.getInt(0);
            String address = c.getString(2);
            if (address.equals(thread)) 
                {
             getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(
             Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
          }
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
}   
}
}
```

and here's my BroadcastReciever class:

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver{

final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {
        if (bundle != null) {
            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
             for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                 SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage
                            .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                 String phoneNumber = currentMessage
                            .getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                 String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                 String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                 Log.i("SmsReciver", "senderNum: " + senderNum
                            + ", message: " + message);
                   MainActivity.setSmsDetails(senderNum, message);

                    // notifikasi sms                    
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Sender: "
                                + senderNum + ", Message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();

                   MainActivity del = new MainActivity();
                   del.delete_thread("5556");

             }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("SmsReciver", "Exception smsReciver" + e);

    }
}   }
```

Comment: "...when the apps on running..." - Do you mean when the app _is_ running, or is _not_ running?

Comment: i mean running @MikeM.

Comment: Since you're talking about pre-KitKat, you can just set the priority on your `<receiver>` to 999, and call `abortBroadcast()` in the Receiver if the number matches. However, if the user has another app installed that takes priority over yours, you might not ever get the broadcast in the first place. Furthermore, odds are that the message hasn't been written to the Provider at the time your Receiver gets the broadcast, which is probably why your current method isn't working. Either way, it's pretty involved if the `abortBroadcast()` doesn't work and you have to delete the text from the Provider

Comment: alright gonna try it soon.

Comment: @MikeM. im using abortBroadcast() and it works for a specific sender. this method prevent sms going to inbox, isnt it?

Comment: Provided that you've got the priority set to 999 on the `<receiver>` in the manifest, aborting the broadcast will generally stop it from reaching the native SMS app, which is the app that usually writes the messages to the inbox in versions <4.4. But, as I said previously, if the user has another SMS app installed that has a higher priority than yours, this might not work. For example, Hangouts and GO SMS Pro are apps that can interfere with this.